# AppleScript and wget

Tags: applescript, wget

I am trying to download a file from a url using `wget`. If I do this in Terminal it works:

```
cd ~/Desktop/diffTest/tempFile
wget "http://www.testsite.com/diffTest/file1.html
```

If I try this AppleScript I get an error:

```
do shell script "cd ~/Desktop/diffTest/tempFile"
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/wget 'http://www.testsite.com/diffTest/file1.html'"
```

Error message:

```
error "--2019-10-21 14:43:28--  http://www.testsite.com/diffTest/file1.html
Resolving www.testsite.com (www.testsite.com)... 66.96.xxx.31
Connecting to www.testsite.com (www.testsite.com)|66.96.xxx.31|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 369 [text/html]
file1.html: Permission denied

Cannot write to ‘file1.html’ (Permission denied)." number 3
```

I don't understand the error message as I'm not trying to write to a file but download it. There is no existing file to overwrite, the folder is empty. The folder has permission for read/write for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The second shell script line ignores the directory change.

You have to put both commands into one line, the semicolon is the command separator

```
do shell script "cd ~/Desktop/diffTest/tempFile; /usr/local/bin/wget 'http://www.testsite.com/diffTest/file1.html'"
```

Comment: seriously, all freaking day because I was using a pipe and not a semicolon. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: @PruitIgoe Each "do shell script" starts a **new process**, separate from any others, same as it would if you ran one `bash` script after another in Terminal.

Comment: I'd recommend using `&&` instead of `;` between the commands -- if the `cd` command fails (e.g. if the directory doesn't exist), this will keep it from trying to run `wget` in the wrong place.